# Mixing RESTEasy Reactive and RESTEasy Classic server parts is not supported

Tags: quarkus, resteasy

I have been upgrading Quarkus to 3.7.2. So while creating a build I'm getting an exception as :-

> **Build step io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.common.deployment.ResteasyReactiveCommonProcessor#checkMixingStacks threw an exception: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: Mixing RESTEasy Reactive and RESTEasy Classic server parts is not supported**

Sharing dependencies for reference :-

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-config-yaml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-junit5-mockito</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-jupiter-params}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-health</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.trino</groupId>
        <artifactId>trino-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${trino-jdbc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-agroal</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-test-security-jwt</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-hazelcast</artifactId>
        <version>${hazelcast.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-kubernetes</artifactId>
        <version>${hazelcast-kubernetes.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Couldn't find the root cause for this exception. I'm excepting the build should get successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove all dependencies with `<groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>`